# How to implement basic 2d graphics/use them in java

Tags: java

So as you can probably tell from my question I am very new at all of this. I am creating a small "particle simulator" (really just gravity thing). I am modeling both X and Y positions. My question is how do I incorporate graphics. I don't really care about re-working my existing code (in java application format). In my prevois research I came along Jquery and Css but I am not sure on how to implement either or them. Also in researcher I found java graphics but I am not sure on what or if library's are involved in making that would I only found commands. I have used them before but that was in a fake environment(codeacdemy). I have created a small GUI in netbeans using a Jframe. That leads into a somewhat second question of what would I use in a GUI to have something graphically involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a tutorial on how to use graphics in java:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html